# Definite integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos( \pi n x)}{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

does anyone have a reference or solution for this integral?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(\pi n x)}{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}} dx$$

$n$ is an integer and $c$ a real number. I tried some tables of integrals and also Mathematica, but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: What makes you think this has a "nice" representation?

Comment: Non-elementary. Why do you need such integral?

Comment: I have no clue that a "nice" representation exists. I need it for a physical problem.